# Is there a standardized symbol/refdes for PCB mounting points?

Tags: schematics, symbol

I've seen a variety of different parts substituted in for mounting locations, including 1-pin header, test pad, and fiducial symbols. I've also seen a variety of reference designators for mounting locations, including M?, MT?, and MP?.

Is there a standard schematic symbol for mounting locations to remove this ambiguity?

Likewise, is there a standard reference prefix?

Comment: I've seen MH used in several places as well, but in my experience mounting holes are not generally labeled.

Comment: MP is used for Mechanical part, H for hardware or holes, up to you. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator

Comment: I don't think there's an official symbol for it but you're pretty spot on about the reference designator. Usually in the schematic you'd just draw a box with a circles representing each pin.

Comment: are you talking about a hole in the PCB?

Comment: Could be a mounting hole, could be a SMT mounting standoff a la 9774030151R (which is the one I'm adding to my library at the moment)

Comment: I usually see these holes (if they even show up on the schematic) are marked with `HOLE_Xmm_n` where "x" is the size in mm and "n" is the number (sequential), similarily for `MOUNT_Xmm_n`. This removes ambiguity about what it is for. Really the only time they need to show up on the schematic is if they connect to ground or chassis.

Comment: I use the ref des for mounting holes as MTGH and the schematic symbol using two concentric circles, colored. "The great thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from."  -Maxim Integrated